# What happen when npm install -g was executed

Tags: linux, node.js

this is a very newbie question. But I really cannot figure it out through Google search.
I want to understand what happens when one executes

```
   sudo npm install -g "node module name"
```

I understand that the right module will be installed to, normally, /usr/local/....
However, why would this be available globally?

For example, I installed **node-inspector** locally in my project. But my shell does not understand when I type "node-inspector".

But once I install it globally,

> node-inspector &

command will does the right thing for me.
I really want to understand how this happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [the npm's doc](https://npmjs.org/doc/folders.html):

> - Local install (default): puts stuff in `./node_modules` of the current
>     package root.
> - Global install (with `-g`): puts stuff in `/usr/local` or
>     wherever node is installed.
> - Install it locally if you're going to
>     `require()` it.
> - Install it globally if you're going to run it **on the
>     command line**.
> - If you need **both**, then install it in both places, or use
>     `npm link`.

It's quite a short description (which, I suppose, is still enough to see the difference), but the linked page describes the whole process of installing modules with `npm` in more details. )